# How do I relate a taxonomy with a custom field type, on another custom field type?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I need to create a tiered relationship between posts in WordPress - I am using ACF (Advanced Custom Fields).

The end result is to create menus (food menus).  There can be multiple menus (Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner), which will all have their own pages.  On each menu will be a section ("Bread & Olives", "Starters, "Mains", "Burgers", etc.), and within that section will be the individual menu items (consisting of the name, description and price).

Currently, I have this set up as:

- Menus - A custom post type, consisting of just a Title
- Menu Items - A custom post type, consisting of a title, description, price
- Menu Section - A taxonomy (category, not tag) of Menu Items

The problem is that a section needs to apply to only a single menu, not multiple.  So, as the admin adding the menu items I need to be able to select the Menu it is linked to ("Evening"), which then populates a list of 'Sections' associated with that Menu.

Currently I can only list all Menus and all Menu Sections, so I need to some how create a relationship between those two when adding a Menu Item.

My question: How can I create this relationship, or am I approaching the problem incorrectly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your project right, the Menu should be another Taxonomy and not a custom post type. You can add more than one Taxonomy per post type.

This way you can create the Menu Item and associate it to one taxonomy (Menu Section, Starters, Burgers) and then add another box to associate the type (breakfast, lunch)

Here's an example of a Project I worked recently:

[image]

So, by parts:

1. The Custom Post Type Projects has associated two custom taxonomies - Categories and Portfolios. This item, in your case would be your Menu Items;
2. Portfolios would be your menus: Lunch, Breakfast, dinner, etc;
3. Categories Can be "bread and olives", "Starters", etc

This way you have all your associated data inside the same post and you can loop it easily with the get_terms() function.

About ACF, I've never worked with this one specifically, however I worked with others in the past that allowed to add a similar box to the post page.

Comment: This is close to what I was after, but I wanted to be able to have tiered taxonomies.  So, if I select "Evening Menu" from taxonomy 1 the second taxonomy box would populate with available options ("Starters, Mains, Burgers, etc").  In the admin area, not the front end (which is the easy part).  This is certainly a step in the right direction though, thank you

Comment: It's easy to do that, the "Porfolios" in my example can accept child categories.